# Help Installing Wine Mono

Tags: terminal, install, wine

I installed Wine Mono from its Git page (by git clone), their README file says

> To build Wine Mono, use the msi or bin target.
>
> $ make msi

So I go to the directory (cd) then do `make msi` it outputs:

```
GNUmakefile:54: *** 'wine' command not found. Please install wine or specify its location in the WINE variable.  Stop.
```

so I follow the other option `make bin`

```
GNUmakefile:54: *** 'wine' command not found. Please install wine or specify its location in the WINE variable.  Stop.
```

so I try `make /bin`, and the sane happens.

Am I doing something wrong, also I may not have one of the dependencies, I do not know what are

> - libgdiplus, to support Mono's resource compiler.
> - The dos2unix command.

And I use a macOS 10.15.7 so I may not have (I don't know what is autotools, and I can install CMake again if required)

> - All of the dependencies of Mono for your native (presumably Linux)
>   system, such as autotools, CMake and a C++ compiler.

EDIT: It also throws errors about libgnutls, like this:

```
0009:err:winediag:gnutls_initialize failed to load libgnutls, no support for encryption
```

Answer (score 2):

It has a pretty explicit README...

> Wine Mono is a package containing Mono and other projects, intended as
> a replacement for the .NET Framework (4.x and earlier) in Wine. It
> works in conjunction with Wine's builtin mscoree.dll, and it is not
> intended to be useful for any other purpose.

And a pretty explicit list of dependencies including...

> - Wine, for the winemsibuilder and cabarc commands. A 32-bit Wine is
>   not necessary, despite the warnings when running 64-bit Wine.

If you are expecting this to be Wine itself, you are mistaken.

Comment: You mean Wine, for the winemsibuilder and cabarc commands is not the WineIsNotAnEmulgator which allows me to open Windows applications on Mac (at least those who don't want ASP.NET). So what should I install, can you give me a link or a instruction please.

Comment: Not I, I have no use for WINE and could not advise you.  I merely actually read instructions.